# How to deal with a very large array with Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures, large-data

First of all, sorry for my very bad English but I'm Italian and I don't know this language well, I hope you'll understand me.
I have to deal with a very large array of Strings (or a different type of data structure), particularly I have to search if a determinate word (or part of it) is contained in this array, exactly like a dictionary.
I have this list of words in a txt file, is there a way to deal with these words without load them to a data structure?
If not, what do you recommend to use?
Thank you

Comment: You could compare each word as and when you read from the file...

Comment: Consider Ann indexed, in-memory database.

Comment: Check out this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/fast-way-of-searching-for-a-string-in-a-text-file

Comment: If you have to look through it a lot sort it and put in a tree, though I don't think there's a standard implementation

Comment: How BIG is VERY LARGE?

Comment: but generally google 'fastutil', which comes from italy.

Comment: I'm talking about tens of thousands strings, if I have to scroll through the list item by item, the execution can become very slow.
As Mar Johnson, the best solution to the problem is a tree, I developed a personal version of the suffix tree and it works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I has already written, I found the solution in a version of suffix tree that I developed.
If it can be useful, I quote here the code:

```
   /* developed by Christian Traina
    * email address: crissstian96@gmail.com
   */

public class Alpha {
private Alpha[] alpha = new Alpha[26];
private boolean mark = false;

// SEARCH
public boolean search(String s){
    return search(s.toCharArray());
}
public boolean search(char[] s){
    return search(s,0);
}
private boolean search(char[] s, int p){
    if(p==s.length)
        return mark;
    if(alpha[s[p]-97]!=null)
        return alpha[s[p]-97].search(s, p+1);
    else
        return false;
}

//MATCHES
//THE ASTERISK MEANS ANY CHARACTERS
//FOR EXAMPLE, IF YOU WANT TO SEARCH A WORD OF SIX LETTERS THAT BEGINS WITH THE LETTER A, 
//YOU HAVE TO PASS "A*****"
public boolean matches(String s){
    return matches(s.toCharArray(), 0);
}
private boolean matches(char[] s, int p){

    if(p==s.length)
        return mark;
    if(s[p]=='*'){

        for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
            if(alpha[i]!=null && alpha[i].matches(s,p+1))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
    else if(alpha[s[p]-97]!=null)
        return alpha[s[p]-97].matches(s, p+1);

    else
        return false;
}


// ADD

public void add(String s){
    add(s.toCharArray(), 0);
}
public void add(char[] s){
    add(s,0);
}
private void add(char[] s, int p){
    if(p==s.length)
        mark=true;
    if(p>=s.length)
        return;
    if(alpha[s[p]-97]==null)
        alpha[s[p]-97] = new Alpha();
    alpha[s[p]-97].add(s, p+1);
}


//PRINT
//IT PRINTS ALL THE ITEMS OF THE TREE


public void print(){
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        if(alpha[i]!=null){
            alpha[i].print(Character.toString((char)(i+97)));
        }
    System.out.println();
}

private void print(String str){
    if(mark)
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        if(alpha[i]!=null){
            alpha[i].print(str+Character.toString((char)(i+97)));
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem right then you can just read the File character by character and add them into a String that represents 1 Word (Maybe build a class so you can make a class.getNextWord()) and then check this word against your array. like:

```
while(class.hasWords()) {
    boolean foundWord = false;
    String word = class.getNextWord();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(word.compareTo(words[i])==0) {
            foundWord = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    ...doSomething...
}
```

where class is what i suggested above

Comment: Why are you looping twice? What's `words `?

Comment: He has got words in a Text File and words in an array so first loop goes for every word in the file and second loop checks every word in the array ->  "I have to deal with a very large array of Strings"  , "I have this list of words in a txt file"         

So words would be the array and word is a String representing the actual word that is getting checked out of the file

Comment: Oh ok. I thought these were the same list of words and he was wondering how to put the words from the text file into the array

Comment: I am not sure what he/she really wants, but that is what I understand and maybe I am wrong and you are right  but its up to him/her to decide :D

Comment: Yep I was just confused. Your way is more fun anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it could help you..

```
public String stringArrayCompare()
{
    for(i=0; i<stringArrayName.length;i++)
    {
        if(StringArrayName[i].matches(.*+"String_Pattern"+.*)// .* indicates any number of characters at the start of the string or in the end, use as per your code requirement.
        {
          return StringArrayName[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use input/output stream to load the words from the file to different array and then search it with what ever words you want to search